# C# create table from datagrid (only 2 fields)

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

but cant find any information.  Restricted on time.

I have a Datagridview, 6 fields.

I need to make a Datatable that only contains 2 of those fields.

fields are part and pareto.

so I need all the records but only want 2 of the fields in my Datatable.

Using c sharp .net 4.0 and Microsoft visual studio 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach( DataGridViewRow row in myDataGridView.Rows)
{
      DataRow tableRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
      tableRow.Cells["part"].value = row["part"].value;
      tableRow.Cells["pareto"].value = row["pareto"].value;
      myDataTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
}
```

Something like this should do it. Just make sure your DataTable has the appropriate rows.

Comment: now i tried this very version before but it errors at the foreach.
Foreach cannot operate because datagridview does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator"

Comment: DataGridview.Rows does though, are you sure you added the .Rows at the end?

Comment: ah my mistake i was missing out the damn thing by mistake, thats not the original problem, the problem i have is the one i am getting yet again: error: Error 2 'object' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: so drop the .value on the one without the value. I thought that would be a prob but don't have time to check it right now. try either tableRow["pareto"] = row["pareto".value, or else try tableRow["pareto"].value = row["pareto". But intellisense will tell you which one has a value property and which does not. Also you might need some additional casting like .ToString() etc...

Comment: Oops, I forgot you need a .Cells. for the GridViewRow - I'll edit it above.

Answer (score 2):

```
DataGridViewRowCollection coll = dataGridView1.Rows; 

DataTable t = new DataTable(); 

t.Columns.Add(); 

foreach (DataGridViewRow item in coll) 

{
     t.Rows.Add(item.Cells[0].Value);
}
```

Just add the Cells you want from every row. All you need to do is filter the Columns.

Comment: tad curious with this one, if you had 2 fields, how would this work? since your looping for an individual cell with no assignment?

Comment: This one is looping through datagrdiview.rows as well, so it's looping through the rows, not the cells. item.Cells[0] is getting the first cell, item.Cells[1] will get the second etc...